# Efficient way to add multiple columns to weekly data in data.table, based on other values of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have data with this structure:

```
a <- data.table(week = 1:52, price = 101:152)
a <- a[rep(1:nrow(a), each = 12),]
a$index_in_week <- 1:12
```

How do I efficiently create 12 new columns that will hold values of prices for next 12 weeks? So, for each week we have 12 rows of data, with index column by week, so it's always in range(1,12). The new columns should contain prices of following 12 weeks starting from current, with a step of 1 week. For example, for week 1 the first new column will have prices of week 1 to 12, column 2 will have values of week 2 to 13, and so on.
I.e., here is how one can create the first two columns:

```
a$price_for_week_1 <- apply(a, 1, function(y) {
  return(head(a[week == (y[[1]]+y[[3]]-1), price], 1))
})
a$price_for_week_2 <- apply(a, 1, function(y) {
  return(head(a[week == (y[[1]]+y[[3]]+0), price], 1))
})
```

Here is an example of a `for` loop:

```
for (i in 1:12) {
  inside_i <- -2+i
  a[, paste0('PRICE_WEEK_', i) := apply(a, 1, function(y) {
    return(head(a[week == (y[[1]]+y[[3]] + inside_i), price], 1))
  })]
}
```

The ways to do it as I see it (e.g. `for` loop or `apply` family) consumes too much time, and I need efficiency.
What would be the way with `data.table` or maybe, as all columns are integer, some funky `matrix` operations?

P.s. I couldn't come up with better title, my apologies.

Comment: Can you describe the logic a bit more?

Comment: You mean, why I need those? I'm mining features for my xgboost model.

Comment: It is based on the prices of the following weeks. For example, `column_5` for week 20 will have values of prices in `[week20+5 : week20+5+12]` slice

Comment: No, I'm asking you to describe in words the logic that you apply to get the new columns. So far, your only written explanation is "values of prices for next 12 weeks". That's not self-explanatory.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. For each week we have 12 rows of data, with index column by week, so it's always in range(1,12). The new columns should contain prices of following 12 weeks starting from current, with a step of 1 week. For example, for week 1 the first new column will have prices of week 1 to 12, column 2 will have values of week 2 to 13, and so on.

Comment: Looks like it could be done using `a[, paste0("col", 1:12) :=  shift(price, n = 0:11+(index_in_week-1), type = "lead"), by = index_in_week]`

Comment: Wow, very straightforward, elegant and pretty fast. Haven't seen the `shift` function before, that's exactly what I need. Please, post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to create a table for 52 weeks (rows) where the prices for the subsequent 12 weeks are printed horizontally.

For this, it is *not* necessary to create a data.table of 12 x 52 = 624 rows and an `index_in_week` helper column. [docendo discimus has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500634/efficient-way-to-add-multiple-columns-to-weekly-data-in-data-table-based-on-oth#comment89972318_51500634) to apply the `shift()` function on the enlarged (624 rows) data.table.

Instead, the `shift()` function can be applied directly to the data.table which contains weeks and prices (52 rows).

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(week = 1:52, price = 101:152)
print(a, nrows = 20L)
```

> ```
>     week price
>  1:    1   101
>  2:    2   102
>  3:    3   103
>  4:    4   104
>  5:    5   105
> ---           
> 48:   48   148
> 49:   49   149
> 50:   50   150
> 51:   51   151
> 52:   52   152
> ```

```
a[, sprintf("wk%02i", 1:12) := shift(price, n = 0:11, type = "lead")]
print(a, nrows = 20L)
```

> ```
>     week price wk01 wk02 wk03 wk04 wk05 wk06 wk07 wk08 wk09 wk10 wk11 wk12
>  1:    1   101  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108  109  110  111  112
>  2:    2   102  102  103  104  105  106  107  108  109  110  111  112  113
>  3:    3   103  103  104  105  106  107  108  109  110  111  112  113  114
>  4:    4   104  104  105  106  107  108  109  110  111  112  113  114  115
>  5:    5   105  105  106  107  108  109  110  111  112  113  114  115  116
> ---                                                                       
> 48:   48   148  148  149  150  151  152   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
> 49:   49   149  149  150  151  152   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
> 50:   50   150  150  151  152   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
> 51:   51   151  151  152   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
> 52:   52   152  152   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
> ```